How to create a trait that requires Drop to be overridden?
Consider a trait which requires a certain cleanup method to be implemented and also ensure that this cleanup is actually performed when an instance is dropped. That we can write something like this:
trait MyTrait {
    fn cleanup(&self);
}

struct MyStruct;

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn cleanup(&self) {
        println!("Cleaning up");
    }
}

impl Drop for MyStruct {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        <Self as MyTrait>::cleanup(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let x = MyStruct;
    }
    println!("done");
}

and it will work, but it does not force the implementation of Drop on MyStruct and it might be easily omitted.
Is there a way to define MyTrait in a way that will ensure or provide a default implementation of drop() calling cleanup()?

You want to check if a trait has been implemented and that their implementation calls a particular method? Sounds fragile. I suppose you could add a new trait which promises they provide the specified Drop. Smells like an XY Problem. What problem are you solving with this?

@Schwern Think of a structure implementing some kind of memory mapping or allocation that can be implemented on top of different hardware. I want this mapping to be destroyed once it is going out of scope, but it needs to de-initialize the underlying hardware. So the implementation should provide the deinitialization sequence which ideally should be called automatically on drop.

A bit of a hack (and at that one that's enforced only at runtime): initialisation could issue a token (an instance of some, possibly zero-sized, type) whose Drop handler panics; your MyTrait::cleanup could then require that token to be passed as argument whereupon it would call std::mem::forget upon it.  To avoid their programs panicking, users must either call the cleanup method or quite deliberately do something creative with the token to avoid that happening.  It therefore should catch accidental, though clearly not malicious, misuse.

@eggyal In fact the code I am looking to integrate it into is "panic-free", and will fail building if panicking code is present.. so perhaps your method would work in build-time.. Need to try it out.

Actually, come to think of it, can't the Drop handler for the "token" just call cleanup itself?  Then user structs would just store the token in a field, and when the struct is dropped cleanup will get called automatically irrespective of whether Drop has been implemented for them or not.

Using trait MyTrait: Drop enforces target structs to implement the Drop trait, but providing a default implementation may need extra effort.

@Raeisi Drop is an autotrait, so I don't think it will have any effect

@eggyal I played around with the token trick, but I am trying to make it private in the. MyTrait and only constructible using a builder. But it does not allow "forgetting" it on drop. Will play with your other idea tomorrow...

@eggyal I couldn't come up with anything sensible with this idea.. So the token would need to refer back to the containing struct, which complicates things...

@EugeneSh. Drop is not an auto trait. Don't confuse the Drop trait with the destructor. The destructor invokes Drop::drop if implemented, then invokes the destructor on every field. The destructor is always generated by the compiler. trait MyTrait: Drop will indeed produce an error for types that don't implement Drop, even if they have a nontrivial destructor.

@FrancisGagné Thanks. I was not aware of this and was under impression that calling a destructor for every type is basically a default auto-implementation of Drop ..

Here's a possible solution using a macro:
mod library {
    pub trait MyTraitImpls {
        fn cleanup(&self);
    }

    /// Users are forbidden from implementing this.
    #[doc(hidden)]
    pub trait __Private {}
    
    /// Implement via `MyTraitImpls` and `impl_my_trait!(...)`
    pub trait MyTrait: MyTraitImpls + __Private {}
    
    impl<T: MyTraitImpls + __Private> MyTrait for T {}
    
    #[macro_export]
    macro_rules! impl_my_trait {
        ($name: ident) => {
            impl library::__Private for $name {}
        
            impl Drop for $name {
                fn drop(&mut self) {
                    <Self as library::MyTraitImpls>::cleanup(self);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

use crate::library::*;

struct MyStruct;
impl MyTraitImpls for MyStruct {
    fn cleanup(&self) {
        println!("Cleaning up");
    }
}
impl_my_trait!(MyStruct);

The user could bypass this by impl library::__Private for MyStruct {} but at least you can't do that accidentally.
You could write this as a procedural macro (#[derive(MyTrait)]) to make it more idiomatic.

I have converged to an implementation which is arguably over-cautious, but seems to provide the required functionality. It requires a wrapper type though. Here is an example of generic "mapping" API, where the implementer is required to provide the code for performing the mapping and the code for unmapping (cleanup in the original question).
mod mapping {
    use std::marker::PhantomData;
    
    pub struct Token {
        _priv: PhantomData<()>,
    }

    pub trait MappingTrait
    {
        type Params;
        fn map(params: Self::Params, _t: Token) -> Self;
        fn unmap(&self, _t: Token);
    }

    pub struct Mapping<M: MappingTrait>
    {
        mapping_impl: M,
    }
    
    impl <M: MappingTrait> Mapping<M> {
        pub fn new(params: M::Params) -> Self {
            Self {
                mapping_impl: M::map(params, Token {_priv: PhantomData} ),
            }
        }
    }

    impl<M: MappingTrait> Drop for Mapping<M> {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            self.mapping_impl.unmap(Token {_priv: PhantomData});
        }
    }
}

The required implementation of MappingTrait requires the map and unmap methods to use a parameter of Token type, which is not constructable outside of the module, so the implemented type cannot be used "directly" even in the module it is implemented in.
Then there is a wrapper type Mapping<M: MappingTrait>, which can internally construct Token and use the provided API. It is also implementing Drop, where unmap of the wrapped type is called.
Here is the example usage:
use mapping::*;

struct MyMappingImpl
{
    some_data: usize,
}

impl MappingTrait for MyMappingImpl {
    type Params = usize;
    
    fn map(params: usize, _t: Token) -> Self {
        println!("Mapping {}...", params);
        MyMappingImpl {some_data: params}
    }
    
    fn unmap(&self, _t: Token) {
        println!("Unmapping {}...", self.some_data);
    }
}


fn main() {
    {
        let _m: Mapping<MyMappingImpl> = Mapping::new(42);
    }
    println!("Done");
}

This code will print
Mapping 42...
Unmapping 42...
Done

Link to Playground
